How would I send console output like an echo command instead of like a command where each time i have to type echo & how to open termnal instantly?
PROBLEM 1
I am trying to write a C++ file which creates tmux panes and have different threads assigned to different panes so that threads have their own window to show console output. Something like this
// Function to display a message in a specific tmux pane
void display(const std::string& sessionName, int paneId, const std::string& message) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(displayMutex);
    std::string command = "tmux send-keys -t " + sessionName + "." + std::to_string(paneId) + " \"echo " + message + " \" Enter";
    std::system(command.c_str());
}

// Function to be executed by each thread
void threadFunction(int threadId, const std::string& sessionName, std::atomic<bool>& running) {
    while (running.load()) {
        std::string message = "HI";
        display(sessionName, threadId, message);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}

now this does work to display in the tmux panes but it executes as a command. This runs the display function every half second
Program Output
but each time when it wants to print anything it has the folder name on the left then each output needs a echo then displays the message in new line as the message. How it looks
~/Code/CPP/tmuxEx$ echo HI
HI

versus what i want is
HI

just the message without the file name showing or executing it as a command.
I can't store the output in a file and then display as i want this to work asynchronously so that the message have a timestamp with it.
PROBLEM 2: The tmux session starts and shows the panel after the entire cpp file completes execution. Meaning the Image shared is the output but it doesn't show the console working but just gives the panes with output after execution.

You used tmux send-keys to "type" commands into the interactive shells running in the tmux panes. Each shell behaved like any other interactive shell: it echoed (or let the line discipline echo) what you typed, it printed a prompt each time a command completed.
This is a very cumbersome way to run something in tmux.
The right way to run something in tmux is to give some shell code directly to new-session, new-window, split-window, respawn-session or respawn-pane tmux command. E.g.:
tmux split-window 'echo foo; sleep 5'

Depending on the settings, the new pane will or will not be destroyed when sleep 5 exits. See "Terminating the tmux session" in this answer of mine.
It seems you don't really need to run anything; you just want ttys that will display messages from your program. To create a pane that does not disappear by itself, run tail -f /dev/null in it. To know the tty of a pane, ask tmux about #{pane_tty} of the pane.
I do not know C++. This is how you would do this in a shell:
# create a new tmux session with two panes
pane1="$(tmux new-session  -d -s foo -PF '#{pane_id}' 'tail -f /dev/null')"
pane2="$(tmux split-window    -t foo -PF '#{pane_id}' 'tail -f /dev/null')"
# get ttys of the panes
tty1="$(tmux display-message -p -t "$pane1" '#{pane_tty}')"
tty2="$(tmux display-message -p -t "$pane2" '#{pane_tty}')"

Use tmux attach-session -t foo in a separate terminal to see the two panes.
At this point you can print to the panes from the original shell:
date >"$tty1"
echo foo >"$tty2"
echo bar | tee "$tty1" "$tty2"

In many cases it makes sense to open each tty once and just use the descriptor later on:
exec 3>"$tty1" 4>"$tty2"
echo baz >&3
uname >&4
echo qux >&3

or even redirect the stdout of the entire shell (exec >"$tty1"), so every future child will inherit it by default; this may be troublesome in an interactive shell, but useful in a shell script.
Finally, when the ttys are no longer needed, close the descriptors and kill the panes or the whole session at once:
exec 3>&- 4>&-
# tmux kill-pane -t "$pane1"
# tmux kill-pane -t "$pane2"
# We want to kill the whole session at once, so the above commands
# have been commented out. We could use them though.
tmux kill-session -t foo
# There is also kill-window.

As I said, I don't know C++; you need to port this procedure by yourself. The point is you shall not use interactive shells and tmux send-keys. Set up tmux session(s), window(s) and panes, query tmux for relevant ttys, open the ttys from your program and print to them directly. At the end kill the tmux panes or window(s) or session(s) if this is what you want.

The tty idea is correct. It works for my case. Thank you very much but it still seems to show the output terminal only when the entire program has done execution so will need to research more

@KaranPatel You need to run a tmux client where you want to see the output and the client needs to attach to the session (tmux attach-session -t foo) and to reconfigure the terminal being its stdout. Does your program do this? For testing you can do this manually. When you manually run tmux attach-session -t foo in another terminal during execution of the program, do you see the panes having been created and the output being printed?

The program is creates a session and splits the window into two panes "tmux new-session -d -s foo -PF '#{pane_id}' 'tail -f /dev/null'" and splits the session as well with "tmux split-window -t foo -PF '#{pane_id}' 'tail -f /dev/null'" but the I can't run the attach "tmux attach -t foo" it seems before running the display command using "tmux display-message -p -t " + pane1 + " '#{pane_tty}'". If the timeline is 1)create session 2)attach 3)display then it makes the session but the output is not consoled out but when i run (1)-(3)-(2) then the program works but it console end

@KamilMaciorowsski The Output only shows when program has the attach at the end and when exited it shows the ttl name "/dev/pts/2" "/dev/pts/3" "/dev/pts/9" "[exited]"  but when attach in the middle or when the pane is created then the consoles have no output and when i exit then it says "Failed to open tty: /dev/pts/9" "Failed to open tty: /dev/pts/2" "Failed to open tty: /dev/pts/3"

@KamilMaciorowsski Solved the issue it seems the problem was that I had to wait for joining the threads to the main thread so by using daemon threads I was able to solve the issue of seeing real time output. Thank you very much

@KaranPatel The site works best when there is one issue per question. Your question contains two problems. I believe I have solved one of them, you have accepted the answer, this is OK. The right thing to do now is to remove the other problem from the question (edit it) and to ask a new question. In the new question please provide mcve. Also note that programming questions are off-topic here on Super User. From a shell script the approach should work, so the problem may be specific to programming (buffering issue?).

@KamilMaciorowsski Will keep that in mind. Thank you for being patient with me.
